# pyspark: ship jar dependency with spark-submit

Tags: python, elasticsearch, apache-spark, pyspark

I wrote a pyspark script that reads two json files, `coGroup` them and sends the result to an elasticsearch cluster; everything works (mostly) as expected when I run it locally, I downloaded the `elasticsearch-hadoop` jar file for the `org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat` and `org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable` classes, and then run my job with pyspark using the `--jars` argument, and I can see documents appearing in my elasticsearch cluster.

When I try to run it on a spark cluster, however, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/spark/spark_test.py", line 141, in <module>
    conf=es_write_conf
  File "/root/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1302, in saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile
    keyConverter, valueConverter, jconf)
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/root/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$getKeyValueTypes$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(PythonRDD.scala:611)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$getKeyValueTypes$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(PythonRDD.scala:610)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$getKeyValueTypes$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$getKeyValueTypes$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:609)
    at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.getKeyValueTypes(PythonRDD.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(PythonRDD.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

which seems pretty clear to me: the `elasticsearch-hadoop` jar is not available on the workers; so the question: how do I send it along with my app? I could use `sc.addPyFile` for a python dependency, but it won't work with jars, and using the `--jars` parameters of `spark-submit` doesn't help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `--jars` just works; the problem is how I run the `spark-submit` job in the first place; the correct way to execute is:

```
./bin/spark-submit <options> scriptname
```

Therefore the `--jars` option must be placed before the script:

```
./bin/spark-submit --jars /path/to/my.jar myscript.py
```

This if obvious if you think that this is the only way to pass arguments to the script itself, as everything after the script name will be used as input arguments for the script:

```
./bin/spark-submit --jars /path/to/my.jar myscript.py --do-magic=true
```

Comment: How could including jars be accomplished if one did not want to use spark-submit, and instead wanted a more interactive session such as an interactive shell within an IDE or notebook?

Comment: hi @trianta2 the `pyspark` command supports `--jars` as well, and will open up an interactive shell for you, so `./bin/pyspark --jars elasticsearch-hadoop-2.1.0.Beta3.jar` will work just fine