# PySpark No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://dbhost

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to write my dataframe to a mysql table. I am getting `No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://dbhost` when I try write.

As part of the preprocessing I read from other tables in the same DB and have no issues doing that. I can do the full run and save the rows to a parquet file so it is definitely reading from the mysql DB.

I am submitting using:

`spark-submit --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/user/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar --driver-class-path /home/user/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar --jars /home/user/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar main.py`

And I am writing using:

`df.write.jdbc(url="jdbc:mysql://dbhost/dbname", table="tablename", mode="append", properties={"user":"dbuser", "password": "s3cret"})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug related the the classloader. This is the ticket for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8463 and this is the pull request for it: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/6900.

A workaround is to copy mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar to every machine at the same location as it is on the driver.

Comment: "to every machine at the same location"? I've just one machine and the driver is at a single location. What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you may have triggered a bug in Spark SQL. There seems to be a fix, the commit is `e991255e7203a0f7080efbd71f57574f46076711` (see https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-commits/201505.mbox/%3C6ec5793fb810447388384f3ac03ca670@git.apache.org%3E ) and it describes the problem as "The problem is in `java.sql.DriverManager` class that can't access drivers loaded by Spark ClassLoader." Probably the simplest solution is to try the latest version from master, or failing that cherry-pick the commit into your branch.