# pyspark mysql jdbc load An error occurred while calling o23.load No suitable driver

Tags: mysql, jdbc, docker, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use docker image [sequenceiq/spark](https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/spark/) on my Mac to study these [spark examples](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html), during the study process, I upgrade the spark inside that image to 1.6.1 according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887227/how-to-upgrade-spark-to-newer-version/33914992#33914992), and the error occurred when I start the `Simple Data Operations` example, here is what happened:

when I run `df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url",url).option("dbtable","people").load()` it raise a error, and the full stack with the pyspark console is as followed:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
16/04/12 22:45:28 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Python version 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015 15:22:56)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
>>> url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root;password=myPassWord"
>>> df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url",url).option("dbtable","people").load()
16/04/12 22:46:05 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/04/12 22:46:06 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/04/12 22:46:11 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
16/04/12 22:46:11 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
16/04/12 22:46:16 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/04/12 22:46:17 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 139, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:50)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createConnectionFactory(JdbcUtils.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

>>>
```

Here is what I have tried till now:

1. Download `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar`, and put it in to `/usr/local/spark/lib/`. It still the same error.
2. Create `t.py` like this:

   ```
   from pyspark import SparkContext  
   from pyspark.sql import SQLContext  

   sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSQL")  
   sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)  
   df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url",url).option("dbtable","people").load()  

   df.printSchema()  
   countsByAge = df.groupBy("age").count()  
   countsByAge.show()  
   countsByAge.write.format("json").save("file:///usr/local/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8/db.json")
   ```

then, I tried `spark-submit --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar --driver-class-path mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar --jars mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar --master local[4] t.py`. The result is still the same.

3. Then I tried `pyspark --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar --driver-class-path mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar --jars mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar --master local[4] t.py`, both with and without the following `t.py`, still the same.

During all of this, the mysql is running. And here is my os info:

```
# rpm --query centos-release  
centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.2.x86_64
```

And the hadoop version is 2.6.

Now I don't where to go next, so I hope some one can help give some advice, thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ran into "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver" when I tried to have my script write to MySQL.

Here's what I did to fix that.

In script.py

```
df.write.jdbc(url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3333/my_database"
                  "?user=my_user&password=my_password",
              table="my_table",
              mode="append",
              properties={"driver": 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'})
```

Then I ran spark-submit this way

```
SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1/libexec spark-submit --packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39 ./script.py
```

Note that SPARK_HOME is specific to where spark is installed. For your environment this https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark/blob/master/README.md might help.

In case all the above is confusing, try this:
In t.py replace

```
sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url",url).option("dbtable","people").load()
```

with

```
sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("dbtable","people").option("driver", 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver').load()
```

And run that with

```
spark-submit --packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39 --master local[4] t.py
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: is it possible somehow to set these --packages while running it inside PyCharm as a normal .py file without spark-submit because I want to debug it within the IDE.  spark.setConf("spark.jars.packages", "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.40") with SPARK_HOME/lib containg jar is not working

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get this to work using the `--jars` flag instead of `--packages` in my submit command. For example: `--jars /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar`

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using the following command

```
import findspark
findspark.add_packages('mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.11')
```