# PySpark to MySQL Insert Error?

Tags: python, mysql, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to learn PySpark and have written a simple script that loads some JSON files from one of my HDFS directories, loads each in as a python dictionary (using json.loads() ) and then for each object, extracts some fields.

The relevant info is stored in a Spark Dataframe and I want to insert this data into a MySQL Table (I created this locally).

But, when I run this, I get an error with my connection URL.

It says "java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.5] failure: ``.'' expected but `:' found"

At this point:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bigdata?user=root&password=pwd
    ^
```

Database name is "bigdata"

username and password are included above

Port number I believe is correct

Here's the full script I have....:

```
import json 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from pyspark import SparkContext 
from pyspark.sql import Row, SQLContext

SQL_CONNECTION="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bigdata?user=root&password=pwd"
sc=SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

cols = ['Title', 'Site']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

#First, load my files as RDD and convert them as JSON
rdd1 = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/ashishu/Project/sample data/*.json")
rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda kv: json.loads(kv[1])) 

#Read in the RDDs and do stuff
for record in rdd2.take(2):

    title = record['title']
    site = record['thread']['site_full']
    vals = np.array([title, site])
    df.loc[len(df)] = vals

sdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
sdf.show()
sdf.insertInto(SQL_CONNECTION, "sampledata")
```

SQL_CONNECTION is the connection URL at the beginning, and "sampledata" is the name of the table I want to insert into in MySQL. The specific database to use was specified in the connection url ("bigdata").

This is my spark-submit statement:

```
./bin/spark-submit /Users/ashishu/Desktop/sample.py --driver-class-path /Users/ashishu/Documents/Spark/.../bin/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar
```

I am using Spark 1.6.1

Am I missing something stupid here about the MySQL connection? I tried replacing the ":" (between jdbc and mysql) with a "." but that obviously didn't fix anything and generated a different error...

Thanks

**EDIT**

I modified my code as per suggestions so that instead of using sdf.InsertInto, I said...

```
sdf.write.jdbc(SQL_CONNECTION, table="sampledata", mode="append")
```

However, now I get a new error after using the following submit command in terminal:

```
./bin/spark-submit sample.py --jars <path to mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar>
```

The error is basically saying "an error occurred while calling o53.jdbc, no suitable driver found".

Any idea about this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the solution was to create a spark-env.sh file in my /spark/conf folder and in it, have the following setting:

```
export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_CLASSPATH:/<path to your mysql connector jar file>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`insertInto` expects a `tablename` or `database.tablename` thats why its throwing `. expected but : found` error. What you need is `jdbc` dataframe writer i.e. see here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc

something like -

```
sdf.write.jdbc(SQL_CONNECTION, table=bigdata.sampledata,mode='append')
```

Comment: Thanks, so when I tried this (see edit to post for my full change), I get a new error saying "An error occurred while calling o53.jdbc no suitable driver". Have you come across that before?

Comment: may be this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588084/pyspark-mysql-jdbc-load-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o23-load-no-suitable-dri#37422017

Comment: I also tried using --packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.42 but I got the same issue. How do I configure the mysql-connector so that it is recognized as a package? maybe that is the issue. thanks.