# Pull data from RDS MySQL db using pyspark

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, hive, pyspark, amazon-rds

I am using pyspark first time. I am trying to pull data from RDS MySQL database using below code. I have referred to the following links 
[pyspark mysql jdbc load An error occurred while calling o23.load No suitable driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588084/pyspark-mysql-jdbc-load-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o23-load-no-suitable-dri#answer-37422017),
https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/spark-sql-mysql-python-example-jdbc/ and many more. But no luck.

```
from  pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=SparkConf()).getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)

hostname='abc.rds.amazonaws.com'
jdbcPort=3306
dbname='mydb'
username='user'
password='password'

jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(hostname, jdbcPort, dbname)


connectionProperties = {
  "user" : username,
  "password" : password
}

    df=spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table='test', properties= connectionProperties)
    df.show()
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-319dff08eefb> in <module>()
     21 #pushdown_query = "(select * from gwdd_data) test"
     22 #df = spark.read.jdbc(url=url,table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
---> 23 df=spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table='test', properties= connectionProperties)
     24 df.limit(10).show()

~\opt\spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in jdbc(self, url, table, column, lowerBound, upperBound, numPartitions, predicates, properties)
    438             jpredicates = utils.toJArray(gateway, gateway.jvm.java.lang.String, predicates)
    439             return self._df(self._jreader.jdbc(url, table, jpredicates, jprop))
--> 440         return self._df(self._jreader.jdbc(url, table, jprop))
    441 
    442 

~\opt\spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~\opt\spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~\opt\spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o326.jdbc.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.HiveFileFormat not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:247)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:259)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:166)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I don't know how to resolve this error. I have checked that mysql-conenctor-java-5.1.45-bin.jar is present in the SPARK_HOME/jars.

And I tried the above code to implement using SQLCOntext, there also I am getting error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your error is a parameter error for the `jdbc` connection. The parameter `dbtable` doesn't exists. First take a look in the usage of the jdbc [connector for spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc)

And after that you need to connect correctly, here is how you are going to do:

```
my_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbc_url, table='gwdd_data', properties= connectionProperties)
my_df.limit(10).show()
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I implemented that but now I am getting some other error. I have updated question. Please have a look.