# How to install a postgresql JDBC driver in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use pyspark with spark 2.2.0 on a lubuntu 16.04 and I want to write a Dataframe to my Postgresql database. Now as far as I understand it I have to install a jdbc driver on the spark master for it. I downloaded the postgresql jdbc driver from their website and tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983982/how-to-use-jdbc-source-to-write-and-read-data-in-pyspark). I added `spark.jars.packages /path/to/driver/postgresql-42.2.1.jar` to `spark-default.conf` with the only result that pyspark no longer launches.

I'm kinda lost in java land for one I don't know if this is the right format.The documentation tells me I should add a list but I don't know how a path list is supposed to look like. Then I don't know if I also have to specify `spark.jars` and or `spark.driver.extraClassPath` or if  `spark.jars.packages` is enough? And if i have to add them what kind of format are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spark.jars.packages` is for dependencies that can be pulled from Maven (think it as `pip` for Java, although the analogy is probably kinda loose).

You can submit your job with the option `--jars /path/to/driver/postgresql-42.2.1.jar`, so that the submission will also provide the library, that the cluster manager will distribute on all worker nodes on your behalf.

If you want to set this as a configuration you can use the `spark.jars` key instead of `spark.jars.packages`. The latter requires Maven coordinates, rather then a path (which is probably the reason why your job is failing).

You can read more about the configuration keys I introduced on [the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment).

Comment: do I still have to tell spark that this is the driver to use? I now run the application with the `--jars /path/to/jar` argument and in the application environment I see the entry: `spark://myip:51810/jars/postgresql-42.2.1.jar Added By User` but when I run the code I get the `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o47.jdbc.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver` exception

Comment: Probably so, try adding `properties={"driver": 'org.postgresql.Driver'}` or `.option("driver", 'org.postgresql.Driver')` (shamelessly copied - and edited - from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37422017/3314107)