# pyspark MQTT structured streaming with apache bahir

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mqtt, spark-structured-streaming, apache-bahir

I'm using spark 2.4 and I've run pyspark like this:

```
./bin/pyspark --packages org.apache.bahir:spark-sql-streaming-mqtt_2.11:2.3.2
```

pyspark runs successfully. 
(But when I run spark-sql-streaming-mqtt_2.11:2.4.0-SNAPSHOT, got an error)

I'm trying to get data from a MQTT broker using structured streaming.
so, I've run this

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import split
>>> spark = SparkSession \
...     .builder \
...     .appName("Test") \
...     .getOrCreate()
>>> lines = spark.readStream\
...     .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")\
...     .option("topic", "/sensor")\
...     .option("brokerUrl", "tcp://localhost:1883")\
...     .load()
```

the error shown:

```
2019-03-22 01:24:43 WARN  MQTTUtils:51 - If `clientId` is not set, a random value is picked up.
Recovering from failure is not supported in such a case.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 400, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o43.load.
: MqttException (0)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence.checkIsOpen(MqttDefaultFilePersistence.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence.getFiles(MqttDefaultFilePersistence.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MqttDefaultFilePersistence.close(MqttDefaultFilePersistence.java:142)
    at org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSource.stop(MQTTStreamSource.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried to stream MQTT data for a week. But I don't think there is a way to solve it and it is really desperate. Is there no way I can solve it?
Thank you.

Comment: "But when I run spark-sql-streaming-mqtt_2.11:2.4.0-SNAPSHOT, got an error"
Is it relevant ?

Comment: looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588084/pyspark-mysql-jdbc-load-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o23-load-no-suitable-dri

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `persistence` option.

Example :

```
   val lines = spark.readStream.format("datasource.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
  .option("topic", topic)
  .option("persistence","memory")
  .option("brokerUrl",broker)
  .option("cleanSession", "true")
  .load()
```

Comment: if I want to persist it in memory and disk... how can I do that?