# Apache spark JDBC connection read write driver missing

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi there are already many questions out there regarding this topic,
the solution always was:

- include driver via sbt-assembly
- use spark-submit`s option --packages
  to load them on the fly

I set up a minimum example here: https://github.com/geoHeil/sparkJDBCHowTo, trying both methods but none worked for me. Getting `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix:
[Apache Spark : JDBC connection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821518/apache-spark-jdbc-connection-not-working?rq=1)
adding `prop.put("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")` works fine.

The strange thing is, the connection does not seem to be stable e.g. with the hive-context it only works 1 out of 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

That’s pretty straightforward. To connect to external database to retrieve data into Spark dataframes, an additional `jar` file is required.

E.g. with MySQL the JDBC driver is required. Download the driver package and extract `mysql-connector-java-x.yy.zz-bin.jar` in a path that’s accessible from every node in the cluster. Preferably this is a path on shared file system. 
E.g. with Pouta Virtual Cluster such path would be under `/shared_data`, here I use `/shared_data/thirdparty_jars/`.

With direct Spark job submissions from terminal one can specify `–driver-class-path` argument pointing to extra jars that should be provided to workers with the job. However this does not work with this approach, so we must configure these paths for front end and worker nodes in the `spark-defaults.conf` file, usually in `/opt/spark/conf` directory.

Place Any `jar` that depends upon what server you using in:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /"your-path"/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar

spark.executor.extraClassPath /"your-path"/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar
```