# How to load table from SQLLite db file from PySpark?

Tags: python, sqlite, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science

I am trying to load table from a SQLLite .db file stored at local disk. Is there any clean way to do this in PySpark?

Currently, I am using a solution that works but not as elegant. First I read the table using pandas though sqlite3. One concern is that during the process schema information is not passed (may or may not be a problem). I am wondering whether there is a direct way to load the table without using Pandas.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

db_path = 'alocalfile.db'
query = 'SELECT * from ATableToLoad'

conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
a_pandas_df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)

a_spark_df = SQLContext.createDataFrame(a_pandas_df)
```

There seems a way using jdbc to do this, but I have not figure out how to use it in PySpark.

Comment: What schema information? You mean datatypes? Not that sqlite *really* has them...

Answer (score 4):

So first thing, you would need is to startup pyspark with JDBC driver jar in path
Download the sqllite jdbc driver and provide the jar path in below .
https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar

```
pyspark --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=<jdbc.jar> --driver-class-path <jdbc.jar> --jars <jdbc.jar> --master <master-URL>
```

For explaination of above pyspark command, see below post

[Apache Spark : JDBC connection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821518/apache-spark-jdbc-connection-not-working)

Now here is how you would do it:-

Now to read the sqlite database file, simply read it into spark dataframe

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').\
     options(url='jdbc:sqlite:Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite',\
     dbtable='employee',driver='org.sqlite.JDBC').load()
```

`df.printSchema()` to see your schema.

Full Code:-
https://github.com/charles2588/bluemixsparknotebooks/blob/master/Python/sqllite_jdbc_bluemix.ipynb

Thanks,
Charles.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @`charles gomes` answer:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
           .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0')\
           .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
        .options(driver='org.sqlite.JDBC', dbtable='my_table',
                 url='jdbc:sqlite:/my/path/alocalfile.db')\
        .load()
```

For other JAR versions please reference the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc)