# How to read sqlite file in Synapse Notebook(PySpark) without using pandas lib

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I have an sqlite 'chinook.db' file in my Azure data lake gen 2 Storage .
The above file is from https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/

So I tried the following code :

```
storage_account='sname'
container='dev'
file_path='raw'

# Define Azure Blob Storage URL and table name
azure_blob_url = f"abfss://{container}@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/{file_path}/chinook.db"
table_name = "employees"


# Create a DataFrame by specifying the driver class name explicitly
df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", azure_blob_url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .load()

# Show the DataFrame
df.show()
```

I have uploaded the sqlitejdbc jar in my Sparkpool :[image]

Still am facing this error :
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o5097.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: **No suitable driver**

**So what can be the Work around guys ?????????**

Answer (score 0):

Answer adapted from this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67019519/3238085

You have to specify the jar in the SparkSession as I have done. Your problem will get solved.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession



spark = SparkSession.builder\
           .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0')\
           .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
        .options(driver='org.sqlite.JDBC', dbtable='customers',
                 url='jdbc:sqlite:../data/chinook.db')\
        .load()

df.show(n=20, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+----------+---------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------+-----+--------------+----------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------------+------------+
|CustomerId|FirstName|LastName   |Company                                         |Address                             |City               |State|Country       |PostalCode|Phone             |Fax               |Email                        |SupportRepId|
+----------+---------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------+-----+--------------+----------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------------+------------+
|1         |Luís     |Gonçalves  |Embraer - Empresa Brasileira de Aeronáutica S.A.|Av. Brigadeiro Faria Lima, 2170     |São José dos Campos|SP   |Brazil        |12227-000 |+55 (12) 3923-5555|+55 (12) 3923-5566|luisg@embraer.com.br         |3           |
|2         |Leonie   |Köhler     |null                                            |Theodor-Heuss-Straße 34             |Stuttgart          |null |Germany       |70174     |+49 0711 2842222  |null              |leonekohler@surfeu.de        |5           |
|3         |François |Tremblay   |null                                            |1498 rue Bélanger                   |Montréal           |QC   |Canada        |H2G 1A7   |+1 (514) 721-4711 |null              |ftremblay@gmail.com          |3           |
|4         |Bjørn    |Hansen     |null                                            |Ullevålsveien 14                    |Oslo               |null |Norway        |0171      |+47 22 44 22 22   |null              |bjorn.hansen@yahoo.no        |4           |
|5         |František|Wichterlová|JetBrains s.r.o.                                |Klanova 9/506                       |Prague             |null |Czech Republic|14700     |+420 2 4172 5555  |+420 2 4172 5555  |frantisekw@jetbrains.com     |4           |
|6         |Helena   |Holý       |null                                            |Rilská 3174/6                       |Prague             |null |Czech Republic|14300     |+420 2 4177 0449  |null              |hholy@gmail.com              |5           |
|7         |Astrid   |Gruber     |null                                            |Rotenturmstraße 4, 1010 Innere Stadt|Vienne             |null |Austria       |1010      |+43 01 5134505    |null              |astrid.gruber@apple.at       |5           |
|8         |Daan     |Peeters    |null                                            |Grétrystraat 63                     |Brussels           |null |Belgium       |1000      |+32 02 219 03 03  |null              |daan_peeters@apple.be        |4           |
|9         |Kara     |Nielsen    |null                                            |Sønder Boulevard 51                 |Copenhagen         |null |Denmark       |1720      |+453 3331 9991    |null              |kara.nielsen@jubii.dk        |4           |
|10        |Eduardo  |Martins    |Woodstock Discos                                |Rua Dr. Falcão Filho, 155           |São Paulo          |SP   |Brazil        |01007-010 |+55 (11) 3033-5446|+55 (11) 3033-4564|eduardo@woodstock.com.br     |4           |
|11        |Alexandre|Rocha      |Banco do Brasil S.A.                            |Av. Paulista, 2022                  |São Paulo          |SP   |Brazil        |01310-200 |+55 (11) 3055-3278|+55 (11) 3055-8131|alero@uol.com.br             |5           |
|12        |Roberto  |Almeida    |Riotur                                          |Praça Pio X, 119                    |Rio de Janeiro     |RJ   |Brazil        |20040-020 |+55 (21) 2271-7000|+55 (21) 2271-7070|roberto.almeida@riotur.gov.br|3           |
|13        |Fernanda |Ramos      |null                                            |Qe 7 Bloco G                        |Brasília           |DF   |Brazil        |71020-677 |+55 (61) 3363-5547|+55 (61) 3363-7855|fernadaramos4@uol.com.br     |4           |
|14        |Mark     |Philips    |Telus                                           |8210 111 ST NW                      |Edmonton           |AB   |Canada        |T6G 2C7   |+1 (780) 434-4554 |+1 (780) 434-5565 |mphilips12@shaw.ca           |5           |
|15        |Jennifer |Peterson   |Rogers Canada                                   |700 W Pender Street                 |Vancouver          |BC   |Canada        |V6C 1G8   |+1 (604) 688-2255 |+1 (604) 688-8756 |jenniferp@rogers.ca          |3           |
|16        |Frank    |Harris     |Google Inc.                                     |1600 Amphitheatre Parkway           |Mountain View      |CA   |USA           |94043-1351|+1 (650) 253-0000 |+1 (650) 253-0000 |fharris@google.com           |4           |
|17        |Jack     |Smith      |Microsoft Corporation                           |1 Microsoft Way                     |Redmond            |WA   |USA           |98052-8300|+1 (425) 882-8080 |+1 (425) 882-8081 |jacksmith@microsoft.com      |5           |
|18        |Michelle |Brooks     |null                                            |627 Broadway                        |New York           |NY   |USA           |10012-2612|+1 (212) 221-3546 |+1 (212) 221-4679 |michelleb@aol.com            |3           |
|19        |Tim      |Goyer      |Apple Inc.                                      |1 Infinite Loop                     |Cupertino          |CA   |USA           |95014     |+1 (408) 996-1010 |+1 (408) 996-1011 |tgoyer@apple.com             |3           |
|20        |Dan      |Miller     |null                                            |541 Del Medio Avenue                |Mountain View      |CA   |USA           |94040-111 |+1 (650) 644-3358 |null              |dmiller@comcast.com          |4           |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------+-----+--------------+----------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: I have tried the code like : from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
    .options(driver='org.sqlite.JDBC', dbtable='employees',
             url='jdbc:sqlite:abfss://dev@stacc1.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/chinook.db') \
    .load()
throwing an error :  An error occurred while calling o4069.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: path to 'abfss://dev@stacc1.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/chinook.db': '/mnt/var/hadoop/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/trusted-service-user/appcache/application_1697037050028_0001/container_1697037050028_0001_01_000001/abfss:' does not exist

Comment: @AzSuryaTeja  : you need to follow the steps mentioned in this blogpost to access abfss file storage. 

https://medium.com/@murali.suraparaju/pyspark-adls-gen2-connectivity-using-abfss-859ef9d313c

Comment: i can access other files like csv excel and jsons . Its throwing error with Sqlite db file. Thats the issue.

Comment: The error says its searching for the file within temp directories spark creates for its operations and not in the abfss path.

Comment: but am giving the right path only.

Comment: You need to follow the steps given in the medium blogpost to achieve results.

Comment: Arey am trying pyspark in Synapse , My synapse alsready has access to my storage acc. There is no need of setting up configs .If iam using a jupyter notebook or databricks ,then these are neccessary steps mentioned in Medium link . As i have already mentioned , i am able to access other files like csv in My storage, the problen exists with sqlite file. Can you drop solution for that but not to access the storage. Can you try the code in your Synapse Workspace , the code will not work.