# Cannot read from Elasticsearch using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, elasticsearch, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

perhaps there's someone out there that can help me. 
I'm trying to read data from ES using PySpark. My Jupyter Notebook code is pretty simple:

```
import pyspark
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('Test').setMaster('spark://spark-master:7077')
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
es_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    inputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat",
    keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
    valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
    conf={
        "es.resource": "some-log/doc",
        "es.nodes": "192.168.1.25",
        "es.port": "9200"
    })
```

I have Spark and Jupyter Notebook installed on the host running the NB. The spark-defaults.conf file is loading the "elasticsearch-hadoop-6.4.0.jar" via: `spark.jars /opt/maya/es-hadoop/elasticsearch-hadoop-6.4.0.jar`

I can connect to the ES instance and read from it by using other tools like `elasticsearch-py`, the `Test` app shows up in the Spark Master UI. However, when I execute the code above, I keep getting this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-5-c990f37c388b> in <module>
          6         "es.resource": "logs-dfir-winevent-security-*/doc",
          7         "es.nodes": "192.168.248.131",
    ----> 8         "es.port": "9200"
          9     })
         10 #es_rdd.first()

    /opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in newAPIHadoopRDD(self, inputFormatClass, keyClass, valueClass, keyConverter, valueConverter, conf, batchSize)
        715         jrdd = self._jvm.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD(self._jsc, inputFormatClass, keyClass,
        716                                                    valueClass, keyConverter, valueConverter,
    --> 717                                                    jconf, batchSize)
        718         return RDD(jrdd, self)
        719 

    /opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
       1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
       1256         return_value = get_return_value(
    -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
       1258 
       1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

    /opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
        326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
        327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
        329             else:
        330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDDFromClassNames(PythonRDD.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I've searched and cannot see that the error is in the code itself, I'm having a feeling this issue is more related to bad Spark configuration within the host running the Jupyter Notebook. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this question : [pyspark: ship jar dependency with spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433428/pyspark-ship-jar-dependency-with-spark-submit)

What you need to do is pass the jar of the dependency with the configuration. If you're using a Jupyter notebook, you can add it via `SparkConf()` such as :

```
conf = SparkConf().option('spark.driver.extraClassPath', 'full/path/to/jar')
```

Just change your code to :

```
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('Test').setMaster('spark://spark-master:7077').option('spark.driver.extraClassPath', 'full/path/to/jar')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is:

```
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = \
    '--jars /full/path/to/your/jar.jar pyspark-shell'
```

jars could be download from https://www.elastic.co/downloads/hadoop

works on spark 2.3 and elasticsearch 6.4